# Add handles to SVG polygon points

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to add handles (circles) on each point of my SVG polygon so the user can drag them to change the shape.
I have two buttons on my main page, one for starting to draw a new shape, another one for "Done". Here's my code:

```
const gardenMap = document.getElementById("garden-map");

let pointsArray = [];
let isCreatingField = false;
let fields = [] //to store coordinates

gardenMap.addEventListener('click', function(evt){
    var e = evt.target;
    var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = evt.clientX - dim.left;
    var y = evt.clientY - dim.top;
    if (isCreatingField) {
        pointsArray.push(x +','+ y);
    }
})

function startCreatingField() { //Start button
    isCreatingField = true;    
}

function finishCreatingField() { //Done button
    isCreatingField = false;  
    var field = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
    var pointsString = pointsArray.join(' ');
    field.setAttribute("points", pointsString);
    field.setAttribute("fill", "lime");
    gardenMap.appendChild(field);  
    fields.push(pointsArray);
    pointsArray = [];
    console.log(fields);
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code to try to add handles to the polygon?

Comment: Add more SVG circles and add drag event listeners to them. When they are dragged, changed the `pointsArray` and update the polygon's `points` attribute.